# Is there some way to debug my email's layout with dev tools?

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design

I'm building several email templates (DEM), using table, CSS inline, etc. To test it I'm using litmus.com.

I'm wondering if there is any tools that let me debug email template in any browser using Firebug or dev tools. I have a lot of problems with outlook because it's rendering HTML using the Word engine. I'm looking for some tool that let me write code in that specific environment.

Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must be sure that you're using only css which is supported by most email clients / providers. This table might help you: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answering your question - I don't know the tool to debug email in specific environment but when I was working on email layouts I always tested them in IE7 (actually IE7 mode in dev tools). If everything looked good there, it looked good everywhere.